# Duplicate keys detected in Vue Date Picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using this plugin, [Vue Date Picker](https://github.com/ridewn/vue-date-picker) and I am getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: 'day-'. This may cause an update error.
```

See a demo here, just select a day in the datepicker and view the errors in the console [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7zqqa9f/)

Comment: check [vue-date-picker source code at github](https://github.com/ridewn/vue-date-picker/blob/master/src/DatePicker.vue#L385), scroll to line#=385, due to the author use `''` as day, it causes `v-for` has duplicated  `:key="`day-${day.day}`"` at line#=79.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the source of the issue. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you really like to use **Vue Date Picker**, copy the sources codes to your project, then uses '-1', '-2' etc instead of '' when padding the days of previous month.